# how can i get all properties and attribute display name of database table entity framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

for example i have model class like that :namespace DomainModelLayer

```
   public class Article:BaseModel
    {
        // id in base model long Id;
        [Display(Name = "عنوان")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "محتوا")]
        [UIHint("_SummerNote")]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Content { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "تاریخ مطلب")]
        public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "دسته مطلب")]
        public long ArticleCategoryId { get; set; }
        public ArticleCategory ArticleCategory { get; set; }

    }
```

and in **db Context** set articles table

```
     public virtual DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
```

in Generic Repository i need get **_t** properties and name (ex: Title , عنوان ), no need to pkey and fkey.

```
  public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseModel
    {
      private readonly IDbSet<T> _t;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private IQueryable<T> _db;
        protected BaseRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _t = _unitOfWork.Set<T>();
             _db = _t;
        }

      public virtual string[] GetAllNameOfDbfileds()
        {
            return typeof(_t).GetProperties()
                .Select(property => property.Name)
                .ToArray();
        }
    }
   }
```

above doesn't work , i no have idea for get properties and names .
and get me an error

> The type or namespace name '_t' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: ``typeof(x)`` doesnt work with variables use ``typeof(T)``

Comment: use _t.GetType() instead of typeof(_t)

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov `_t.GetType()` will return the wrong type.

Comment: Right to @RandRandom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeof(x)` doesnt work with variables use `typeof(T)`, if you want to get the Type of a variable you have to use `_t.GetType()` but in your case that would return the Type of `IDbSet<T>` instead of only `T` so just simply use `T`.

To get the `Display Attribute` you have to use the following:

```
public virtual string[] GetAllDisplayNames()
{
    return typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(property => ((DisplayAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault())?.Name).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to get type use `typeof(T)` or `_t.GetType()`
and then use method `GetProperties()` on that